# sls offline start, serverless Warning: found unsupported runtime 'nodejs8.10' for function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-offline

Whenever I tried to run the serverless framework offline by using

> sls offline

[image]

I am getting this warning for every function.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Serverless Offline that has been fixed in a newer release - https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/381

Have you tried upgrading Serverless Offline?

Comment: Yes, I already tried the latest serverless offline npm module.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used **s-function.json** file, And In this file, I changed

"runtime": "nodejs" instade of "nodejs8.10", also add endpoints

```
"endpoints": [
      {
        "path": "func-name",
        "method": "POST",
        "requestParameters": {
          "htmlContent": true
        },
        "requestTemplates": {
          "application/json": {
            "payload": "$input.json('$')"
          }
        }
      }
  ],
```

And This works for me.